# Cinema 4D to WebGL with controls?

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, cinema-4d

I'm not entirely sure if this even possible (I'm new to 3D models online and such), but could I somehow get a Cinema 4D model (with colors + textures) to display on the web with mouse rotate controls?

I've looked around and people mention Three JS a lot but I'm not sure if that would work, or how I would even go about getting it to work. Again, I'm pretty new to the whole 3D thing. Sorry if this is not possible, and thank you.

Comment: What is Cinema 4D model? is that just a 3D model or is it 4D? Seems to be just a 3D modelling tool but I want to make sure.

Comment: @WaclawJasper Yeah. It's a 3D modeling tool, kind of like Blender. It can export to different file types like .3ds, .dae, .obj, etc.

Comment: Yeah then its definitely possible. Check out http://threejs.org/examples/

Comment: Hate to mention this, but are you sure you want to actally *program* this? If you just want it to show on the web, why not use a pre-existing online 3D model library like *Sketchfab* (it has a Cinema4D exporter).